# Which is the correct one "You idiot" OR "you're an idiot"

Tags: sentence-construction, auxiliary-verbs

"You idiot" OR "You're an idiot"

I want to know which one is correct because in the first one there is no auxiliary verb.

As I know if I wanted to say that someone is like someone/thing I'll say
"He is a hero."

So in the previous example we've used an auxiliary verb before a noun.

Comment: @Kyle: *Idiot* might be an insult, but it's not exactly a curse word.

Comment: @Ahmed: There is no auxiliary verb there at all. The verb *to be* in your examples is just being a verb, not an auxiliary verb. "You idiot", or "you bozo", or "you fox", are all fragments, noun phrases that are acceptable as utterances but technically not sentences - due to the lack of a verb.

Comment: @SamBC Would it be correct to say that "are an" is understood?

Comment: @DonB. I would say it's not precisely the same as that, but it's an easy to way to understand the essential meaning. I expect some people would analyse it that way, though.

Comment: @DonB. I would not assume an elided *are an*. It's more simply an imperative—like pointing at something and saying *Look! Chocolate!* If I had to assign something that was omitted, I would make it *You, [acknowledge the] idiot [in front of me].*

Comment: Both sound good to my ear.  The second may be more grammatical, but the first is a perfectly valid insult for someone who just did something stupid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"You idiot" is not a sentence. It's a noun phrase headed by the noun "idiot". "You" is a personal determinative functioning as a determiner.

"You are an idiot" is a complete sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, "you idiot" is not a sentence.  "You are an idiot" is a complete sentence.

However, sometimes, you use exclamatory expressions without a verb, called elliptical exclamatives. So it's right to say:

You idiot!

What a beautiful house!